# Facebook api get all the messages from a user in a fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to get all the messages posted by a user in a facebook fan page. (wall posts and also possible comments to other posts).

Is there an easy way to do that?

Right now i might have to get all the posts from a page, filter by user and do the same with comments but if the page has 3k posts and tons of comments that will be very slow.

I think this might be possible with fql but i cant find how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

this documentation from facebook will show you how to query the posts from the users wall - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

note: The stream table is limited to the last 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater.

that takes care of the huge amount of comments!